# Is it possible to disable JSX validation on docusaurus v2?

Tags: markdown, jsx, docusaurus

I have a website in docusaurus v1 that I am migrating to v2.

It has several docs in `.md` format with embedded HTML tags.

After the migration, the website won't load due to invalid tags.

[image]

Is it possible to disable this JSX validation in v2 and have the same behavior I have in v1?

Comment: I'd also like to know if there's a solution to this. We're aggregating a lot of documentation and some doesn't always have perfect html. Would be good to avoid going back to source for all of them.

Comment: escape the tags with backticks

Answer (score -2):

According to the error message, you are just lacking the closing tag for the HTML element `<td>`, which is `</td>`. Add it and you'll be fine.

The docusaurus error messages are amazingly clear. Follow the instructions to solve the issues.